# Issue: Saving Json data to Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to learn how to read data from a blog and save it to core data but the save is not working as intended. There are 4 blog entries and I expect to have 4 different entries in core data. Please see the code below and let me know where i went wrong:

```
 let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler:{(data , response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil){
            println(error)
        }else{
            var jsonResult:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
            var managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
            let newBlog = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("BlogDetails",inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext) as NSManagedObject
            var dateFormater = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" //"yyyy-MM-dd"
            var readRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BlogDetails")
            for var i = 0; i < ((jsonResult["items"] as? NSArray)?.count)!; i++ {
                var item = jsonResult["items"]![i] as NSDictionary
                var blogAuthorDirectory = item["author"]! as NSDictionary
                var blogAuthor = blogAuthorDirectory["displayName"] as NSString
                var blogAuthorImageDirectory = blogAuthorDirectory["image"] as NSDictionary
                // concatenate String
                var blogAuthorImage =  blogAuthorImageDirectory["url"] as NSString
                var blogAuthorImageUrl = ("https:" + blogAuthorImage)
                var title = item["title"] as String
                // convert date from String
                var publishedDate:NSDate = dateFormater.dateFromString(stringTmp as NSString)!
                // read content
                var content = item["content"] as? NSString
                // Write it to core data
                newBlog.setValue(blogAuthorImageUrl, forKey: "image")
                newBlog.setValue(blogAuthor, forKey: "author")
                newBlog.setValue(title, forKey: "title")
                newBlog.setValue(publishedDate, forKey: "publisheddate")
                managedObjectContext.save(nil)
                var results = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(readRequest, error: nil)
                println(results)
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

following are the entries in result in the last iteration:
1. It only has 3 dictionary counts out of which values in first 2 count has all items as nil. how is that being generated?
2. With every iteration, it overwrites value in last count and doesn't append it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to append objects to your CoreData, you need to do [insertIntoManagedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:) before you call the `managedContext.save(nil)` method.

However, your

```
let newBlog = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("BlogDetails",inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext) as NSManagedObject
```

is declared outside of your for loop, so probably no new blog created after each iteration.

Comment: THANKS for your help!! It worked when I brought the line in the loop. so bottom line for every new dictionary block we have to re-instantiate NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName.